# GridView is scrolling back to top after In-Row Button Click

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scroll, position, state

I have a `GridView` inside an `UpdatePanel`. The GridView (GV) contains In-Row Buttons. If the GV list is very long and press the Buttons on the bottom rows, the page scrolls to the top and I cannot find which button I had clicked.

I have tried, `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"`, but since I am using an `UpdatePanel`, this does not seem to be working.

I would like the screen to remain on the Row where I have clicked the Button.

Answer (score 0):

set `UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Always"`

add this function:

```
  public static string GetPostBackControlId(Page page)
    {
        Control control = null;
        // first we will check the "__EVENTTARGET" because if post back made by the controls
        // which used "_doPostBack" function also available in Request.Form collection.
        string controlName = page.Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"];
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(controlName))
        {
            control = page.FindControl(controlName);
        }
        else
        {
            // if __EVENTTARGET is null, the control is a button type and we need to
            // iterate over the form collection to find it

            // ReSharper disable TooWideLocalVariableScope
            string controlId;
            Control foundControl;
            // ReSharper restore TooWideLocalVariableScope

            foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
            {
                // handle ImageButton they having an additional "quasi-property" 
                // in their Id which identifies mouse x and y coordinates
                if (ctl.EndsWith(".x") || ctl.EndsWith(".y"))
                {
                    controlId = ctl.Substring(0, ctl.Length - 2);
                    foundControl = page.FindControl(controlId);
                }
                else
                {
                    foundControl = page.FindControl(ctl);
                }

                if (!(foundControl is Button || foundControl is ImageButton)) continue;

                control = foundControl;
                break;
            }
        }
        return control == null ? String.Empty : control.ID;
    }
```

use this in `page_load`to get postback controlId:

```
if (IsPostBack)
 {
 string controlName = GetPostBackControlId(this);
}
```